# Continuity of an integral depending on a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definite-integrals

Let $f(x,t)$ be a real-valued function defined over $(a,b)\times [0,1]$. Suppose that $f$ is integrable in $x$ for every $t\in [0,1]$ and let
$$
g(t):=\int_a^b f(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
Suppose also that $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)\times [0,1]$ and that for all $(x,t)$ holds $|f(x,t)|\leq C$ for a positive constant $C$. I would like to show that $g$ is continuous in $t=0$.

**My attempt**

The condition $|f(x,t)|\leq C$ is a good domination condition since $(a,b)\times [0,1]$ has finite measure. Thus we can apply the dominated convergence theorem (DCT). Let $(t_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a sequence in $(0,1]$ such that $t_n\rightarrow 0$. Thus
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+} g(t) = \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} g(t_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \int_a^b f(x,t_n)\,\mathrm{d}x \overset{\rm DCT}{=} \int_a^b f(x,0)\,\mathrm{d}x = g(0).
$$
Is my reasoning correct? I know that this kind of problems (such as continuity and differentiability of integrals depending on a parameter) can be treated with the DCT, but I had some doubts here because I would like to prove continuity in an endpoint of the interval of definition of $t$.

Comment: This argument is fine.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks! I also proved that $g$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ (again with the DCT and with a domination condition on $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)$). This anyway does not necessarily imply continuity in $t=0$, is this right? That should only imply that $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+} g(t)$ exists and not that it is equal to $g(0)$.

Comment: Yes, differentiable on $(0,1)$ does not give continuity at $0$.

Comment: @SoniaP: just a question: doesn't the fact that $|f(x,t)|<C$ follow from integrability of $f$ on $(a,b)$ since if $\int_{x}|f(x,t)|< \infty$ obviously $\exists \ C$ s.t. $|f(x,t)|<C$. What do I miss?

Comment: @Alex That shouldn't be true, because there are integrable functions which are unbounded. Take for instance $f(x,t)=\frac{t}{\sqrt{x}}$ on $(0,1)\times [0,1]$.

Comment: So $\frac{t}{\sqrt{x}}$ is bounded in $x$ on $(0,1)$? but unbounded on, for example $[0,1]$, right? Does it make $f(x,t)$ locally integrable(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function)?

Comment: @Alex The function $x\mapsto \frac{t}{\sqrt{x}}$ is unbounded on $(0,1)$. Nevertheless it is integrable: $\int_0^1  \frac{t}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx = 2t$.